# How to prove that if $E(X^2) < \infty$ then $E(X) < \infty$?

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

> How to prove that if $E(X^2) < \infty$ then $E(X) < \infty$?

Here is my **attempt**:

It's easy to show that if $E(X^2) < \infty$ then $E(X) < \infty$ when $X^2 \ge X$ (by using the monotonicity of expectation).

But how do I prove the case when $X^2 < X$, using only the definition of finiteness of expectation as 
$$
Eg(x) = \int |g(x)|f(x) < \infty?
$$

Comment: $X^2\leq X$ if and only if $X\leq 1$. Moreover $\int 1 dx = 1$ so you're good.

Comment: $$|X|\leqslant X^2+1\quad \text{(QED)}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one reached onto you by the comment of Did is my favourite.

Another one is: $$\mathbb EX^2-(\mathbb EX)^2=\mathbb E(X-\mathbb EX)^2\geq0$$implying that: $$(\mathbb EX)^2\leq\mathbb EX^2<\infty$$

Comment: (+1) A nice quantization of the difference using a common formula for the variance.

Comment: @robjohn Thank you! It has a minus though. It carries some circular reference. Before we can use what is symbolized in $\mathbb EX$ (so that we can use the symbol) we should first have proved that that is a legal thing to do. This legalization however **is** proving that $\mathbb E|X|<\infty$. In this context on base of $\mathbb EX^2<\infty$. This can be done by e.g. the hint of Did.

Comment: Yes, indeed. $\mathbb{E}(X)$ appears in two of the terms, which makes it hard to isolate. Maybe the OP won't notice ;-)

Answer (score 5):

By Jensen inequity for $g(x) = x^ 2$,
$$
g(\mathbb{E}(X)) \le E( g(X) ), 
$$ 
hence, 
$$(\mathbb{E}X )^2 \le \mathbb{E}X^2 < \infty,
$$
thus 
$$
\mathbb{E}(X) < \infty
$$

Comment: (+1) Usually, I am the one using Jensen when others have used Cauchy-Schwarz. It's nice to switch things up once in a while.

Answer (score 2):

[Cauchy-Schwarz (or Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) says
$$
E(X)^2\le E\!\left(X^2\right)E(1)=E\!\left(X^2\right)
$$